# Add ExpandableListView to a tab with other elements

Tags: android, tabs, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am developing an app with tabs. On one of the tabs,
I have two `EditText` fields and a couple of buttons. I want to add an `ExpandableListView`
to the tab, below the rest of the elements.

My problem is that the current class extends `Activity`. All the example I've found extend `ExpandableListActivity`, but I can't extend both for the same class.

How can I add this list to the tab? I've added an `ExpandableListView` element in the `XML` file, but whenever I run it, it doesn't show up. I understand that I need to bind the view to some data, but how do I go about doing this?
Thank you.

Here is my class code:

```
public class DirectionsTab extends Activity 
{
    private Button clear_btn;
    private Button go_btn;
    private EditText origin_txt;
    private EditText dest_txt;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directions_tab);

        // initialize views and onClick event handler
        origin_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.origin_txt);
        dest_txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dest_txt);
        clear_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear_btn);
        // clear all text fields and return focus to dest_txt
        clear_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             origin_txt.setText("");
             dest_txt.setText(""); 
             origin_txt.requestFocus(); 
            }    
        });        
    } // end public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
} // end public class DirectionsTab extends Activity
```

and XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/origin_lbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Origin"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/origin_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/origin_lbl"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dest_lbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/origin_txt"
        android:text="Destination" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dest_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/dest_lbl" />    

    <ExpandableListView
     android:id="@+id/listView"      
     android:layout_below="@+id/dest_txt" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" /><!--android:id="@android:id/list"-->

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/clear_btn"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dest_txt"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"        
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Clear" />
    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/go_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/clear_btn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/clear_btn"
        android:text="Go!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this!, If anyone is having problems with this, make sure you follow these steps:

1. Copy and paste [ExpandableList3](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html) example (located in ApiDemos project from Samples folder in your Android SDK). This is just a good example of how to set up a list.
2. Make your class inherit from ExpandableListActivity
3. Create the following in your XML layout file:

   ```
   <ExpandableListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"       
   android:layout_below="@+id/go_btn" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>
   ```

It is VERY important that the ID property matches what you see above, otherwise, nothing will work. This little detail wasted plenty of hours for me and was discovered seating neatly as a small detail in the android docs.