# Android,want to show Expandible listview in a tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I want to implement tab in my application. Tab works well. Now implementing expandable list view in one of the tab... That means activity extends Fragment and not FragmentActivity... But I face a problem in expendable list view... How can I overcome this... Here is my code..

```
public class ExpandableListView extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;


        public ExpandableListView(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
         if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_battery, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.battery);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }


}
```

And main class is...

```
public class Setting extends Fragment{

    ExpandableListView listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    //private LayoutInflater context;

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         //// context =inflater;

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);


            expListView = (ExpandableListView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) listAdapter);
            return rootView;

        }

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("Remaining Battery");
        top250.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        top250.add("Pick Alarm Tone");
        top250.add("Set Vibrate");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("Remaining Battery");
        nowShowing.add("Set Alarm Distance");
        nowShowing.add("Pick Alarm Tone");
        nowShowing.add("Set Vibrate");


        List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
    }


    }
```

error is constructor "The constructor ExpandableListView(Context, List, HashMap>) is undefined"...

Comment: You have wrong params. pls look @ public constructors http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

This actually is not related to the fact you are using a tab.

You have two classes named `ExpandableListView`, and seem to be importing the wrong one in your `Settings` class.

To circumvent this, I'd recommend choosing a different name for your `Adapter`, so you and the compiler don`t get confused.

Alternatively, you could just change the import at the top of `Settings` to include your own `ExpandableListView` class and change appearances of the actual widget to `android.widget.ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Check this link for detailed answer [Add ExpandableListView Under TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168985/add-expandablelistview-under-tabhost)

Also if you want to add the list in the tab widget itself then you can try this link
[Add ExpandableListView to a tab with other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157095/add-expandablelistview-to-a-tab-with-other-elements)